# How can I report NSFW ad on main site?

Tags: support, advertisements

This is an ad from main site that is shown to me right now:

> [image]

I consider it NSFW, how can I report it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for reporting.  I agree this is NSFW.  We are removing it immediately and should not be apart of our network.

Comment: Is there any way to specify keywords/topic areas of the sorts of ads we might deem relevant to our site?

Comment: @Robotnik we are developing a tool that will give you control of the ad experience.  I dont have a specific date of release, but we are working hard to get it out ASAP.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to it :)

Comment: Thanks for quick action!

Comment: 3 hours later and I see the same ad again :/